# Download a purchased audiobook in Books as a local audio file?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, books, audiobook

I've purchased an audiobook in Apple's Books app on MacOS. I noticed it says "download" but apparently that just means downloading within the Books app, so I can listen there. However I'd like to download it as a stand-alone audio file so I can also listen it in other apps or players.

Is there a way to do this? Or can I see how or where Books has stored or cached the local version of the audiobook?

Any format like MP3, AAC, etc is all fine for me.

If relevant, I'm using Books v2.4 on MacOS Catalina 10.15.

P.S. note that I don't use iTunes, just Books.

Comment: Audio books are DRM-encrypted, and so won't work with other apps.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks, that sucks. I suppose there's no way to decrypt them?
Alternatively, is there a way to play audiobooks purchased in Apple Books on an Android phone? I noticed the Apple Books app doesn't seem to be available on Android, is there another DRM qualified app that could work?